# Content is not modified after updating Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue Js and I tried to modify the content in a .vue file, and when I reload the page my content is not modified.

Here is the code :

```html
<section class="fourth">
  <h2>Des espaces <span>dédiés</span> pour chaque profil</h2>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button-small" :class="{'button-ghost': !student}"
            @click="toggleStudent">Je suis élève
    </button>
    <button class="button-small" :class="{'button-ghost': !parent}"
            @click="toggleSParent">Je suis parent
    </button>
    <button class="button-small" :class="{'button-ghost': !teacher}"
            @click="toggleTeacher">Je suis prof
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div v-if="student">
      <img src="build/images/side-s4.png">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Une plateforme adaptée à tes <span>besoins</span></h3>
        <p>Que tu sois à l’aise ou complètement perdu en mathématiques, profite
          d’un accompagnement personnalisé et efficace adapté à ton profil. Suis
          ta progression de jour en jour et débloque les différents niveaux de
          difficultés pour te perfectionner et devenir un as en mathématiques
          !</p>
        <button v-scroll-to="{ el: '#join', offset: -100 }">DEMANDER UN ACCÈS
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="parent">
      <img src="build/images/side-s4.png">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Une plateforme adaptée à tes besoins</h3>
        <p>
          Êtes-vous intéressés par un compte personnel pour suivre les progrès
          de votre enfant ?<br>
          Ou bien souhaitez-vous bénéficier d'aide et être coaché par une équipe
          d'enseignants pour aider vous-même votre enfant ?
        </p>
        <button v-scroll-to="{ el: '#join', offset: -100 }">Demander à être
          contacté
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="teacher">
      <img src="build/images/side-s4.png">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Une plateforme adaptée à tes besoins</h3>
        <p>
          Vous souhaitez rejoindre une communauté d'enseignants passionnés et
          voulant faire avancer leur métier ?
          <br>
          Ou bien êtes-vous intéressés pour faire bénéficier vos élèves des
          contenus de la plateforme ?
        </p>
        <button v-scroll-to="{ el: '#join', offset: -100 }">Créer mon compte
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I try to modify the content of

```
<button v-scroll-to="{ el: '#join', offset: -100 }">Créer mon compte</button>
```

But the changes do not appear when reloading the page.

How can I make the changes effective immediately?

**EDIT : Here is the content of my package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-loader": "^15.0.11",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "ckeditor": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "sticky-sidebar": "^3.3.1",
    "vue-affix": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-mq": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-qm": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.17.1",
    "vue-sticky-directive": "^0.0.10",
    "vue2-circle-progress": "^1.2.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2 : BLANK PAGE WHEN USE YARN RUN DEV-SERVER**

Here is the output :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about your development environment? E.g. are you using vue-cli, webpack, etc. After you change your .vue file you will then need to build your project it in order to see the changes in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It uses symfony 4, it's not my project so I don't know if there is vue-cli, but there is webpack. How can I build my project ?

Comment: Could you add the contents of your `package.json` file? There might be a build command in there.

Comment: Ok I add the content of my package.json above

Comment: Okay if you want it to continuously build while you make changes, try running `yarn run dev-server`.

Comment: I've got a issue, I make yarn run dev-server but now I have a blank page... And when I stop the process I still have this blank page.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: I have edit my post see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228636/discussion-between-hannah-and-yinyang).